Deployed Django Application on PythonAnywhere: Connection Refused Error When Controlling Raspberry Pi Robot Remotely
I am trying to deploy a Django web application on PythonAnywhere that controls a Raspberry Pi robot remotely. The application worked flawlessly locally using ngrok to establish a connection, but after deploying it to PythonAnywhere, I encountered the following error: 2024-04-17 07:49:53 Connection refused: The server is not accepting connections.
I tried:
Added localhost to the ALLOWED_HOSTS in Django settings.
Tried running the server on a different port.
Disabled the firewall on the Raspberry Pi.
Added corsheaders to the Django project.
